# Unable to use sort() algorithm/error with signed/unsigned mistmatch

Tags: c++, sorting, mismatch

*Please keep in mind that I'm extremely new to C++ so the most direct/simple solution (ideally with an explanation) is preferred.*

I have three questions about this code that I have quite literally copied from Stroustrup's "Programming: Principles and Practice."

Here is the code:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h" //using this header as it is what the book recommends

int main()
{
    vector<string> words;
    for (string temp; cin >> temp;)
        words.push_back(temp);
    cout << "Number of words: " << words.size() << "\n";

    sort(words); //"no instance of overloaded function "sort" matches the argument list"

    for (int i = 0; i<words.size(); ++i) //'<' : signed/unsigned mismatch -- exe still runs in spite of this, not sure what it means
        if (i == 0 || words[i-1]!= words[i])
            cout << words[i] << "\n";

    keep_window_open(); //added because i don't know how else to keep the window open
}
```

I'm getting two errors regarding the sort() algorithm:

```
"error C2780: 'void std::sort(_RanIt,_RanIt)' : expects 2 arguments - 1 provided"

"error C2780: 'void std::sort(_RanIt,_RanIt,_Pr)' : expects 3 arguments - 1 provided"
```

I've searched for both of these online but haven't come across an answer that makes sense to me.

Second, I'm curious about the

```
'<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
```

because it does not stop the program from running. If the answer to this question is too complex for a beginner then feel free to skip it, I'm just interested.

Comment: You might want to read e.g. [this `std::sort` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Comment: sort(words.begin(), words.end())

Comment: words.size() return unsigned size_t, int i is signed (change or cast)

Comment: That overload of `sort` is defined in the "std_lib_facilities.h" provided by the author [here](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code/std_lib_facilities.h), and presumably along with the book.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest checking out what Joachim linked to and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/. When calling sort you must provide it an iterator to start at and an iterator to end at, with an optional third argument that can be your comparison operator.

Below is an example that I made from your code;

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h" //using this header as it is what the book recommends

int main()
{
    vector<string> words;
    for (string temp; cin >> temp;)
        words.push_back(temp);
    cout << "Number of words: " << words.size() << "\n";

    sort(words.begin(),words.end()); //beginning and ending of where you want to sort

    for (uint i = 0; i<words.size(); ++i) //'<' : //changed int to uint
        if (i == 0 || words[i-1]!= words[i])
            cout << words[i] << "\n";

    keep_window_open(); //added because i don't know how else to keep the window open
}
```

As for the signed/unsigned error, ints are signed meaning that they can be negative, so they can be −32,768 to 32,767, where as uints are unsigned meaning that they can be 0 to 65,535.

The code can still work but beware that if word.size() is larger than 32767 and i is an int then i will never grow to be larger than word.size(). i will simply wrap around to -32768 when incremented past 32767. I would suggest using uint as the type of i.